# Is it possible to write non-automatic formalizations in Isar?

Tags: isabelle, proof, isar, hol

I have the following:

```
lemma 
  assumes p: "P"
  assumes pimpq: "P⟶Q"
  shows "P∧Q"
proof -
  from pimpq p have q: "Q" by (rule impE)
  from p q show ?thesis by (rule conjI)
qed
```

I have thought that this is down to basic inference rules but reading the documentation for `rule` in section `9.4.3 Structured Methods` of the Isar Reference Manual it turned out that it uses the Classical Reasoner with various rules. And, replacing the `by` clauses by `..` also solves the goals, so mentioning implication elimination and conjunction introduction is not essential.

Is it possible to write a strict formalization here in Isar, i.e. not to use any automation and extra rules that are not explicit in the program text? Something like a forward proof in HOL4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `Pure.rule` if you don't want to use the `classical` module.

```
lemma 
  assumes p: "P"
  assumes pimpq: "P⟶Q"
  shows "P∧Q"
proof -
  from pimpq p have q: "Q" by (Pure.rule impE)
  from p q show ?thesis by (Pure.rule conjI)
qed
```

If you write `..` Isabelle will automatically select a rule based on lemmas that are marked with the `[intro]` or `[elim]` attribute.

Maybe you can also share your HOL4 proof that you want to reproduce in Isabelle, so that we can suggest the equivalent in Isabelle/HOL.